# Why do I get a "Communications link failure" when trying to connect to the MySQL database?

Tags: java, database, docker

I'm trying to set up my docker for the first time and the MySQL container is running fine, however, when I want to add the container of my application too I get a communication link failure and the container exits.
It's a locally hosted database so not sure if that's an issue
The image of the application is also made, it's just not running in the container and I do not have any errors, my application runs fine normally.

These are my application properties(I got two of  them):

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/avalon
spring.datasource.username=root spring.datasource.password=mypass
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.autocommit=false
```

And this is my `application-staging.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://docker_avalon_db_staging:3306/avalon
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=mypass
```

This is the command I'm using for the application container:

```bash
docker run \
  -d \
  -p 8090:8080 \
  --net=docker_avalon_network_staging \
  --env spring_profiles_active=staging \
  --name=avalon-backend-staging \
  avalon
```

And this is the command I used to set up my db container:

```bash
docker run \
  --net docker_avalon_network_staging \
  --name docker_avalon_db_staging \
  -e MYSQL_DATABASE=docker_avalon_db \
  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypass \
  -p 3390:3306 \
  -d \
  mysql
```

I tried looking through my firewall and stuff but it's not blocking any of that so I wonder what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: When you try to activate the staging Spring profile, do you need to set an environment variable `spring.profiles.active` (with dots) or `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` (uppercase)?  Could you directly pass `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` as an environment variable?